# Symfony how to valid a form after login

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a newAction which creates a form

```
   /**
     * Creates a new Vente entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="vente_new")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request) {
        $vente = new Vente();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\VenteType', $vente);
        return $this->render('vente/new.html.twig', array(
                    'vente' => $vente,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

and an addAction which processes and valides the form after successful login:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Vente entity.
 *
 * @Route("/add", name="vente_new_add")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function addAction(Request $request) {
    //...
    $user = $this->getUser();
    //...

}
```

After login, how to get form data and process it?
I'm thinking of storig the form data in session if user not login and process it after successfull login. But I don't know how to handle it.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the form display and processing in the same controller action it's far simpler this way. I understand that in you case, you want to log the user before processing the form so you must have two actions. Unless you choose to have your form under the same firewall and access control. If you must be an authenticated user with the correct role in order to see and process the form then the two steps can be merged.

Otherwise, you can serialize your Request object or try hydrating the form with the request and serialize your form object. Then you can store this serialized object in session and unserialize. Have a look at JMS Serializer Bundle, it's simple and very efficient.

Comment: I will go with JMS Serializer Bundle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For such cases I usually go with one of the following solutions:

- Make an AJAX login form that is opened in a popup, open it before submitting the form, ensure the submit is performed only if the user is already logged in.
- Save the form information in the DB, with the other data but with a special status, or in a separate table, then only the ID needs to be stored inside the session and linked to the logged in user after submit.